# Proxy for Excel's split cell in R

Tags: r, contingency

Apologies in advance if anyone finds this to be a duplicate to a question answered before. I haven't found anything so here it is:

I have a 3x3 contingency table I made in RStudio (I am specifying this as a data frame below but I can also produce this as as.matrix, if that'll work better):

```
mat.s=data.frame("WT(H)"=11,"DEL(H)"=2)
mat.s[2,1]=13
mat.s[2,2]=500369
row.names(mat.s)=c("DEL(T)", "WT(T)")
mat.s=cbind(mat.s, Total=rowSums(mat.s))
mat.s=rbind(mat.s, Total=colSums(mat.s))
```

which looks like:

```
kable(mat.s)

|       | WT.H.| DEL.H.|  Total|
|:------|-----:|------:|------:|
|DEL(T) |    11|      2|     13|
|WT(T)  |    13| 500369| 500382|
|Total  |    24| 500371| 500395|
```

However, if I wanted to split a cell in this table (like you can do in Excel) into two, how would I do that? So I'd like to get something like the following when I render the document with kable:

```
|       | WT.H.| DEL.H.|  Total|
|:------|-----:|------:|------:|
|DEL(T) | S  D |      2|     13|
|       | 8  3 |       |       |
|WT(T)  |    13| 500369| 500382|
|Total  |    24| 500371| 500395|
```

So that when I want to calculate something from this table, I can call the split 8 or 3. Sorry if this is something very simple and easy to do! Still learning. Thanks!

Comment: How are you defining this split in the data? How complex can it get?

Comment: Hi Spacedman. The complexity is simply just a cell split into two where the split can be defined in any way. I could do a sum based on certain criteria for each cell of the table (and each split) using ifelse or I could do a mean; there's no specific definition. In this case, I have simply used some integers and I should  probably clarify that my question is just about coding for a table that can have a split cell, rather than the values in the cells. Many thanks :)

Comment: What I mean is you need to specify in code or data how that split is done before you can work on outputting it, so eg you could do `splitcell(mat.s,1,1) = data.frame(S=8, D=3))` - then we write `splitcell` and then we work out how to output the table with split cells. That might mean rewriting large chunks of `kable`.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. That's right. I would need to have the code for the data that would go into the split cells first. Thank you pointing me in the right direction though!